# How do I install the latest gcc 4.7.0 on centos 6.2?

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

```
[root@localhost dyliu]# yum list gcc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Installed Packages
gcc.i686                    4.4.6-3.el6                    @anaconda-CentOS-201112130233.i386/6.2
```

By default, if I run `yum install gcc`, the yum tool will install gcc 4.4.6 for me.

Question> How to install the latest gcc [4.7.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on centos 6.2?

Thank you